# Running Rails and PHP on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost

Is it possible to run some PHP pages at "example.com" AND also run a rails application at say "test.example.com" on Dreamhost?  Has anyone done this?

Or do I need to run rails apps on separate domains?

Thanks.

Comment: I think a better place for this would be the dreamhost support forums. This is way too specific for here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Dreamhost control panel menu, go to "Manage Domains" under "Domains".

Add the domain example.com as a fully hosted domain, and keep the default settings.  PHP is set up on fully hosted domains by default, so you're good to go there.

Go back to the "Manage Domains" panel and set up the subdomain test.example.com.  This time, check the box marked "Ruby on Rails Passenger (mod_rails)?" and fill in the form to specify the public folder of your Rails app.  For full details on how to set up a Passenger app in DH, you should check out [the relevant DH wiki article](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger) - the instructions are pretty straightforward.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -4):

You can do it and I have done it.  Not to sound like an advertisement, but their control panel makes it simple to do what you want.